# Polynomial Multiplication | Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, biginteger, multiplication, polynomial-math

I'm training my C++ and I'm trying to write a library that'll be able to represent the following number using XOR linked lists:

**999999999 * ( [i=0]Σ[999999999] 1000000000 ^ i )**

For example if my number was **711381450277869054011**, it'll be represented like this:

**711** * 1000000000^**2** + **381450277** * 1000000000^**1** + **869054011** * 1000000000^**0**

Or simply:

**711** * X^**2** + **381450277** * X^**1** + **869054011** * X^**0**

[image]

I overloaded the `*` operator for my class, but I think the algorithm I used is clumsy.

I was going to go for [Karatsuba algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm), but since it's recursive, it'll lead to stack overflows.

Then I checked [Toom-3 algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom-Cook_multiplication). I liked it, but I couldn't apply it because I still didn't program negative numbers yet.

My question is: What algorithm you suggest, would be best for polynomial multiplication ? Is there any good algorithms I need to see ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Fast Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) to perform it. There also exists non-recursive implementation of it.